# Remove additional text after last parameter in address bar with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^files/page/?([0-9]+)? /files?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

which allows to access different pages like files/page/2

problem is, it also allows for files/page/2/2/2/2/2/2/2/2/2 and so on.

How do I remove the repeating /2/2/2/2 ?.. Tried different solutions but they didn't work out.

Comment: You did not anchor your pattern to the end, so it allows for any arbitrary stuff to come after what you matched.

Comment: Why did you make the slash after `page` optional? You don’t want to allow `files/page2`, or do you? And why are the digits also made optional - is just `files/page/` or `files/page` also supposed to work?

Comment: Because there are different pages. /page/2, page/3, page/4 and so on. I just need to remove everything after the page number, like I said above...

Comment: But yes, you are correct, I forgot the $! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, very sorry, such a silly mistake!

It needs to be:
    RewriteRule ^files/page/([0-9]+)$ /files?page=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Making that slash optional there, still makes rather little sense. Unless you explicitly want to allow for stuff like `files/page2`, which I doubt you actually do.